# This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects (.deployproj) in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects (.deployproj) in visual studio 2015 in (windows 7 32bit)

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
     - AllInOneDeploy, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\AzureAllInOneDeploy\AllInOneDeploy.deployproj"
     - SetupBackups, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\SetupBackups\SetupBackups.deployproj"


No changes required
These projects can be opened in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1 without changing them.
     - Checkbox.Forms.Workflow, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Checkbox.Forms.Workflow\Checkbox.Forms.Workflow.csproj"
     - Checkbox.Wcf.Services, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Checkbox.Wcf.Services\Checkbox.Wcf.Services.csproj"
     - Checkbox.Wcf.Services.LocalProxies, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Checkbox.Wcf.Services.LocalProxies\Checkbox.Wcf.Services.LocalProxies.csproj"
     - Checkbox.Wcf.Services.Proxies, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Checkbox.Wcf.Services.Proxies\Checkbox.Wcf.Services.Proxies.csproj"
     - Checkbox.Web.Charts, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Checkbox.Web.Charts\Checkbox.Web.Charts.csproj"
     - CheckboxWeb, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\CheckboxWeb\CheckboxWeb.csproj"
     - Checkbox, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Core\Checkbox\Checkbox.csproj"
     - Core, "Core"
     - Framework, "Framework"
     - Checkbox.Common, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Core\Checkbox.Common\Checkbox.Common.csproj"
     - Checkbox.Globalization.Text.MultiLanguageTextProvider, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Core\Checkbox.Globalization.Text.Providers\Checkbox.Globalization.Text.MultiLanguageTextProvider.csproj"
     - Checkbox.LicenseLibrary, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Core\Checkbox.LicenseLibrary\Checkbox.LicenseLibrary.csproj"
     - Checkbox.Web, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Core\Checkbox.Web\Checkbox.Web.csproj"
     - Checkbox.Web.Ajax, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Core\Checkbox.Web.Ajax\Checkbox.Web.Ajax.csproj"
     - Checkbox.Web.Providers, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Core\Checkbox.Web.Providers\Checkbox.Web.Providers.csproj"
     - Prezza.Framework, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Core\Prezza.Framework\Prezza.Framework.csproj"
     - Prezza.Framework.Common, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Core\Prezza.Framework.Common\Prezza.Framework.Common.csproj"
     - Enyim.Caching, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Enyim.Caching\Enyim.Caching.csproj"
     - CheckboxDb, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\CheckboxDB\CheckboxDb.csproj"
     - Checkbox, "E:\Prakash\Proj-2112017\survey-platform-master\Checkbox.sln"
```

[image: Migration Report -]

[image: Underline in Red showing not load this project]

Comment: You have to ask a specific question. Read this first  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 15):

I tried multiple options to solve .deployproj unsupported error but none of them worked except below.
Go to Visual studio Installer -> Modify VS 2017
Select Azure Development options and install it. this should work

Comment: Installed Azure Development, removed .vs folder and opened solution again. Error was no more. You saved the day mate.